# Did the Luftwaffe tactically support Tobruk's capture in 1942?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, british-empire, north-africa, libya

In the comic *AfrikaKorps*, the capture of Tobruk in 1942 is highlighted as the consequence of tactical bombings of the Tobruk perimeter. The reasons of the defeat are given as:

- Lack of antitank weapons for Allied troops that are no more connected to supply
- Destruction of the trenches by *Stuka*'s bombings before tanks and infantry assault the position
- The city itself is entered by German tanks only after Commonwealth troops surrendered
- South-African and Australian troops were involved

From my other readings about this battle, I could confirm some of these elements:

- Most tank fighting occurred before the assault on Tobruk itself, during the first phase of the battle of Gazala. However, Allied infantry units knew about the problem of tanks and were well equipped to counter it, as was seen for the French at Bir-Hakeim or the 50th brigade at Sidi-Muftah. At Tobruk were 61 Valentine and Matilda tanks and 14 6-pounder guns, but the perimeter lacked mines and counter-attacks were in disorder*
- The WDAF could only cover Tobruk with Curtiss P-40 fighters with drop tanks, so it is plausible that *Stukas* have operated during "holes". However did they play such an important role?
- Indeed Axis's unit stopped at the 'outskirts of the city" itself on June 21th, and then on June 22th the surrender happened
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_capture_of_Tobruk) mentions mainly the South-African (20 000 combat troops) and some British support units (tank, artillery...). So apparently no Australians and those South-Africans were non-veterans?

## Did the Luftwaffe tactically support Tobruk's capture?

Depends (at least) on the following two questions:

1. Why were counter-attacks so much in disorder, besides misinterpretation of orders? Was it an effect of Axis air power?
2. Was the perimeter too large considering skills, defense preparation and German tank and air superiority?

Comment: Two downvotes, no upvotes.  Is there a way to improve this question that would reverse that trend?  There is clear evidence of research (although uncited, so it isn't possible to examine the validity of the assumptions?)

Comment: Did the Luftwaffe engage in the battle? Yes. But the surrender seems to have been driven as much by a lack of desire to spend the level of resources to withstand a siege that the UK had in 1941 the first time around. Hanging the South Africans out to dry by not publishing the final report was not a good thing for Commonwealth morale.